# Bash 'for' loop syntax?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

What is the syntax for a Bash `for` loop?

I have tried:

```
for (($i=0;$i<10;$i ++))
do
    echo $i
done
```

I get this error:

```
line 1: ((: =0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=0")
```

Comment: [First google search result for "bash for loop" is pretty good](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/), but [this page is much better](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace

```
for (($i=0...
```

with

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++))
```

Comment: @Laurent, reverted as it doesn't fit in with the rest of the answer (replace x by y).

Answer (score 11):

The portable way is:

```
for i in `seq 0 9`
do
    echo "the i is $i"
done
```

Comment: That would loop from 1 to 10 instead of 0 to 9.

Comment: @Laurent: Fixed that. Good catch.

Answer (score 7):

Another way

```
for i in {0..9}
  do
    echo $i
  done
```