# Python command line loop

Tags: python, command, anaconda, mrjob

I'm running a mrjob python script, and in the command line I can pass the number of cores for the system to use.

```
python example_script.py --num-cores 5
```

I'm looking to run the script for n number of cores for beach marking performance test. IE: I want to run it for 1 core, 2 core etc.

Is there anyway I can write a loop directly into the command line rather then having to write out the whole command n number of times?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to test the performance of the script across n number of cores

Comment: But why do you want to pass the number of cores that way? Why not a simple integer? That's what a number of cores is, not a range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash 'for' loop syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854118/bash-for-loop-syntax)

Comment: @mafrasi2 ok, perhaps I wasn't clear. I updated the question there and hope it's clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in you want to lunch 4 isntances of mrjob each with increasing number of cores?

i.e.

```
python mrjob.py --num-core-instances=1
python mrjob.py --num-core-instances=2
python mrjob.py --num-core-instances=3
python mrjob.py --num-core-instances=4
```

In that case I don't think you can. You can make a script that lunches those for you though.

```
import subprocess
for i in range(1,5):
    subprocess.Popen(["start","cmd","/k","python","mrjob.py","--num-core-instance="+i],shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
for i in {1..10} ; do python example_script.py --num-cores $i ; done ;
```

It is a [bash for loop](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/).